# Android error: java.lang.Object cannot be resolved, and missing Android 4.2.2 "directory"

Tags: android

I have 7 projects based on a base project, and they are all basically the same code. I opened my Eclipse today and one of them is giving me the error  The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. I noticed that in that project the "directory" that shows Android 4.2.2 is missing. Can someone help me fix this. Here is a image file that shows what's missing: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=4h44yo&s=5

Can someone please help me out? I'm not an experienced Android dev...

Comment: This is usually just a project build error, I can get rid of them by restarting Eclipse most of the time.

Comment: That worked. user2483079 If you make your response an 'answer' I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually just a project build error, I can get rid of them by restarting Eclipse most of the time.

Comment: I was able to fix it by changing the project's Android build target to a different SDK and back again. Depending on how much you've got going on in your eclipse that might be faster than a restart.